Check using Iframe/JS/? if user was on a website in last 30 days
Situation:

I'm the owner of the website example.com
I want to give my customers the possibility (pixel/iframe/sth?) to check if current visitor of their website was on my website (example.com) in the last 30 days
If she/he was on my website in the last 30 days, the dataLayer event should be fired.

Tried Iframe and embeded JS to read cookies but no success.

How would you determine that visitors of the two websites are "the same"? There's no globally unique way to identify Internet users.

If you do some up with a shared identifier (e.g. they both registered with the same email address), you can simply provide an API that your customers call to check the last date that they used your site.

I think you can try to set Same-Site: None to your cookie on your website (eg somecookie). Then your requests from anotherwebsitecom to websitecom should use it. Then you can check if request contains somecookie.
If you want to limit the cookie's lifetime to 30 days you can use expires property.

I've found a solution, but I'm afraid won't work when Chrome will disable 3rd party cookies:

I'm setting up 30 days cookie on my site (example.com)

I've prepared a simple endpoint on my site (example.com/check):
$content = isset($_COOKIE["xxx"]) && $_COOKIE["xxx"] ? 1 : 0;
$response = new JsonResponse(['response' => $content]);
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
return $response;


my customers can use this code to check it:
 <script>
     (function() {
         var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open('GET', 'https://example.com/check', true);
         xhr.withCredentials = true; 
         xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                 var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

                 if(response.response)
                 {
                     window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                     window.dataLayer.push({
                         'event': 'visited_otodom'
                     });
                 }
             }
         };
         xhr.send();
     })();
 </script>



